Advantage on multiple attacks
I play a multiclass Rogue / Ranger and often use my allies to gain advantage to trigger sneak attack. I'm aware that sneak attack only works once per turn; however, I fight with two weapons and have an extra attack (from Ranger 5). Do I have advantage on the first attack with each hand, all attacks, or just the initial attack with my primary weapon?

Welcome to the site! It's important to remember that there are lots of RPGs out there; can you tell us which game & edition you're asking about?

Note: I'm assuming you are talking about dnd-5e.
I think you're confused about how sneak attack works. The feature states:

Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll. [...]
You don't need advantage on the attack roll if another enemy of the target is within 5 feet of it, that enemy isn't incapacitated, and you don't have disadvantage on the attack roll.

You state that you "use your allies" to gain advantage. I think you are using the alternate trigger case, which allows you to use a conveniently placed ally to trigger the feature. However, this does not actually give you advantage on the attack.
Alternatively, your game might use the optional flanking rules, which offer advantage if you are on the opposite side of the enemy. If this is the case, you would have advantage on every attack against the flanked enemy.
Finally, your allies might be using the Help action, which gives you advantage on your next attack against the enemy. If this is the case, you would only have advantage with the first attack you make on that turn.
